# Class auto loader Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I created a new directory at root '*components*'. Then I put a file '*ClassName.php*' into this folder. Declare a namespace `namespace components;` and the class named `ClassName`  Now I try to use it like

```
$c = new app\components\ClassName()
```

But there's an error. It says that `Class 'components\ClassName' not found`. 
Where am I missing? I suppose that I should add folder components in include_path or something like that. Please help to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

Just add

```
Yii::setAlias('components', dirname(dirname(\__DIR__)) . '/components');
```

In className.php:

```
namespace components;
```

Then usage:

```
$c = new components\ClassName();
```

Comment: This is not a solution, this is a silly hack. What are you going to do make another alias for models? how about controllers? heck make an alias for everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can create custom components in Yii2 (basic application)

Create a folder named "components" in the root of your application.
Then create a class for your component with proper namespace and extend Component class:

```
namespace app\components;
use yii\base\Component;

class MyComponent extends Component {

    public function testMethod() {
        return 'test...';
    }
}
```

Add component inside the config/web.php file:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'mycomponent' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\MyComponent'
    ]
]
```

Now you can access your component like this:

```
Yii::$app->mycomponent->testMethod();
```

Comment: This is the best solution probably, it should go up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `ClassName.php`:

```
namespace app\components;
```

**Added**

When you create new `ClassName` instance, don't forget the leading backward slash for namespace (AKA fully qualified namespace), if your current namespace is not global, because in that case namespace will be treated as relative (Like UNIX paths), use:

```
$c = new \app\components\ClassName();  //If your current namespace is app\controllers or app\models etc.
$c = new app\components\ClassName();  //If your current namespace is global namespace
```

You can read more about namespaces basics in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Answer (score 0):

It should be late but I guest my solution may help some one later. I had the same issue and the resolved it the way bellow:
If you want to autoload (import) a customer class in your app, you to do:

- create your class where ever you want e.g in my case, i created common/core/Utilities.php
- then you have to create an alias (alias is a short cut name you give to your folder path). In my case in create an alias for my folder core (note i should also create an alias for my component folder) e.g

  Yii::setAlias('core', dirname(**DIR**).'/core');

this snippet i put it in my common/config/boostrap.php file. because yii2 load this file at running time.

- Now you are ready to use your customize class where ever you want. Just do

  $utilities = new \core\Utilities();

Hopefully this may !!!!!!!